# How to keep track of row index of the rows I randomly select from a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, random

I am trying to perform tournament selection in a GA whereby I need select two rows randomly. Is there a way of keeping track of the index values of the 2 random rows I select from the matrix self.population and storing those in variables?

At the moment it just outputs the two random rows but I need to keep track of which rows were selected.

Below is what I have so far although ideally I would like to store both rows I select from my matrix in separate variables.

```
self.population = [[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]
                  [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
                  [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
                  [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
                  [0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
                  [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0]]

def tournament_select(self):
    b = np.random.randint(0, self.population[0], 2) 
    return self.population[b]
```

Comment: Just return both arrays: `return b, self.population[b]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
from random import sample
import numpy as np

population = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])


def tournament_select():
    row_indices = sample(range(len(population)), k=2)
    return row_indices, population[row_indices]

row_indices, candidates = tournament_select()
print(row_indices)
print(candidates)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]]
```